# NSTokenField delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nstokenfield

In Apple's "Token Field Programming Guide for Cocoa" in section "Basic Interaction With the Delegate" tells that when the user type some text in token field the delegate receives the `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` message.

And when the user types the tokenizing character delegate receives the `tokenField:representedObjectForEditingString:` message.

So when I implemented this methods its behave themselves in a very different way.

There is my implementation of delegate methods:

```
- (NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenFieldArg
completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring 
           indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex 
    indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex {

NSLog(@"completionsForSubstring: %@", substring);
return [NSArray array];
}    

- (id)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
 representedObjectForEditingString:(NSString *)editingString {

NSLog(@"representedObjectForEditingString: %@", editingString);
return editingString;
}
```

And there is a log when i type "maksim" in token field and then erase it:

> 2011-03-01 19:03:01.286 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: m
>   2011-03-01 19:03:01.287 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: m
>   2011-03-01 19:03:01.493 Aurum[23269:a0f] completionsForSubstring: m
>   2011-03-01 19:03:01.633 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: ma
>   2011-03-01 19:03:01.633 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: ma
>   2011-03-01 19:03:01.637 Aurum[23269:a0f] completionsForSubstring: ma
>   2011-03-01 19:03:03.737 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: mak
>   2011-03-01 19:03:03.737 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: mak
>   2011-03-01 19:03:03.741 Aurum[23269:a0f] completionsForSubstring: mak
>   2011-03-01 19:03:05.089 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maks
>   2011-03-01 19:03:05.089 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maks
>   2011-03-01 19:03:05.094 Aurum[23269:a0f] completionsForSubstring: maks
>   2011-03-01 19:03:05.841 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maksi
>   2011-03-01 19:03:05.841 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maksi
>   2011-03-01 19:03:05.845 Aurum[23269:a0f] completionsForSubstring: maksi
>   2011-03-01 19:03:06.697 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maksim
>   2011-03-01 19:03:06.697 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maksim
>   2011-03-01 19:03:06.701 Aurum[23269:a0f] completionsForSubstring: maksim
>   2011-03-01 19:03:12.353 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maksi
>   2011-03-01 19:03:12.354 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maksi
>   2011-03-01 19:03:12.853 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maks
>   2011-03-01 19:03:12.854 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maks
>   2011-03-01 19:03:12.936 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: mak
>   2011-03-01 19:03:12.937 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: mak
>   2011-03-01 19:03:13.020 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: ma
>   2011-03-01 19:03:13.020 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: ma
>   2011-03-01 19:03:13.103 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: m
>   2011-03-01 19:03:13.104 Aurum[23269:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: m

So can anyone explain me what's going wrong and why token field behave themself so strange?

Comment: I don't see anything strange in the log you posted. What do you expect `NSTokenField` to do???

Comment: I expected that when i typed any symbol NSTokenField would send completionsForSubstring: message to it's deleate. And only after i will enter a tokynized character it will send representedObjectForEditingString: message and only once but not twice.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to reproduce this by copying and pasting your code. I got:

```
2011-03-09 14:52:48.888 StackOverflowTesting[27789:a0f] completionsForSubstring: m
2011-03-09 14:52:49.242 StackOverflowTesting[27789:a0f] completionsForSubstring: ma
2011-03-09 14:52:49.560 StackOverflowTesting[27789:a0f] completionsForSubstring: mak
2011-03-09 14:52:49.911 StackOverflowTesting[27789:a0f] completionsForSubstring: maks
2011-03-09 14:52:50.017 StackOverflowTesting[27789:a0f] completionsForSubstring: maksi
2011-03-09 14:52:50.217 StackOverflowTesting[27789:a0f] completionsForSubstring: maksim
2011-03-09 14:52:50.647 StackOverflowTesting[27789:a0f] representedObjectForEditingString: maksim
```

Which is exactly what'd I'd expect as the output. Have you changed the default tokenizing characters of the NSTokenField? When you hit the tokenizing character, it doesn't look like it tokenized maksim (since after all, you were able to delete it character by character).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I just tried to place in interface another new token field and connect it to delegate, and then a got the same log as you. So i found what was a problem. Old token field was binded to array controller (value binding) .